# Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "Norm" und "Sitte"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Sitte und einer Norm? Wisst ihr, warum es zwei verschiedene Begriffe dafür gibt, obwohl sie doch dasselbe bedeuten? Stimmt es überhaupt, dass die beiden Begriffe dasselbe bedeuten?

Duden listet folgende Bedeutungen von "Sitte" auf:

> 1. für bestimmte Lebensbereiche einer Gemeinschaft geltende, dort übliche, als verbindlich betrachtete Gewohnheit, Gepflogenheit, die im Laufe der Zeit entwickelt, überliefert wurde
> 2. ethische, moralische Norm; Grundsatz, Wert, der für das zwischenmenschliche Verhalten einer Gesellschaft grundlegend ist
> 3. Benehmen, Manieren, Umgangsformen
> 4. (Jargon) Kurzform für: Sittenpolizei

Für mich bedeuten die ersten drei Definition eig. im Grunde genommen dasselbe. Versteht ihr, warum die das nochmal in drei verschiedene Bedeutungen aufgeteilt haben?

Und für "Norm" diese:

> 1. a. allgemein anerkannte, als verbindlich geltende Regel für das Zusammenleben der Menschen
>      b. Rechtsnorm
>      c. (in Wirtschaft, Industrie, Technik, Wissenschaft) Vorschrift, Regel, Richtlinien o. Ä. für die Herstellung von Produkten, die Durchführung von Verfahren, die Anwendung von Fachtermini o. Ä.
> 2. übliche, den Erwartungen entsprechende Beschaffenheit, Größe, Qualität o. Ä.; Durchschnitt
> 3. festgesetzte, vom Arbeitnehmer geforderte Arbeitsleistung
> 4. (Sport) (von einem Sportverband) als Voraussetzung zur Teilnahme an einem Wettkampf vorgeschriebene Mindestleistung
> 5. (Verlagswesen) klein auf den unteren Rand der ersten Seite eines Druckbogens gedruckter Titel [und Verfassername] eines Buches [in verkürzter oder verschlüsselter Form]

1a ist doch eig. genau dasselbe wie die Bedeutungen 1-3 von "Sitte", oder?

Comment: Ich kenne keine DIN-Sitte.

Comment: Die ersten 3 unterscheiden sich insofern, als etwa sich zur Begrüßung die Hand zu reichen eine Umgangsform ist, aber nicht grundlegend für das Zusammenleben (2). Sich nicht in der Nase zu bohren gehört zu 3, nicht zu 1, als es nur negativ definiert ist und keine Gepflogenheit. Nachdem Du selbst siehst, dass es nur eine gewisse Überschneidung der Begriffe gibt fragt sich, was die Antworten noch über Deine Zitate hinaus liefern sollen. Das gleiche in anderen Worten?

Answer (score 4):

Bedeutung 1a von "Norm" stimmt weitgehend mit Bedeutung 2 von "Sitte" überein. In diesem Punkt überschneiden sich die beiden Wortfelder, und in dieser Bedeutung können die Wörter im Einzelfall bis auf stilistische Aspekte austauschbar sein.

Alle anderen Bedeutungen sind dem jeweiligen Wort eigen. Weder kommen Duden-Bedeutung 1, 2 oder 4 von "Sitte" dem Wort "Norm" zu noch Bedeutung 1b, 1c oder 2 bis 5 von "Norm" dem Wort "Sitte".

Daher ist die Titelfrage eindeutig mit "ja" zu beantworten.

Answer (score 1):

Norm ist der deutlich weitere Begriff. Während Sitte und Moral als Normensysteme verstanden werden können gibt es noch andere Normen, nicht zuletzt Rechtsnormen.